# When I access the value of longitude and Latitude, it shows null

Tags: java, android

I used this .getFusedLocationProviderClient to get user coordinates but when I try to access the value of longitude and latitude outside the function block of requestLocationUpdate(), I get null values.

```
 LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext).
                requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext)
                                .removeLocationUpdates(this);
                        if(locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size()>0) {
                            int latestLocationIndex = locationResult.getLocations().size() -1;
                            latitude =
                                    locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLatitude();
                            longitude =
                                    locationResult.getLocations().get(latestLocationIndex).getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: Getting locations is an asynchronous operation. Until `onLocationResult()` is called, you will not have a location to use.

Comment: If anything rely on latitude and longitude to work  ,  Move all your work into onLocationResult().